# Display crashed/corrupted on AnyCubic Prusa I3 clone

Tags: prusa-i3

I've recently completed assembly of an AnyCubic Prusa clone.  It's working, but having some issues.  My prime concern at this point is the LCD display.  It occasionally becomes "corrupted" for want of a better term (see image) and no longer responds to the control.  It's done this unattended in the middle of a print attempt, which means I can't pause it to remove the imminently dripping filament from the leaking extruder (another issue I'm dealing with).
[image: corrupted display]

So three questions I guess...

Is this a typical problem?

What's the likely culprit (main board, display, firmware)?

How to fix it?

I'm working with AnyCubic's tech support, such as it is, and wondering if I need to push them for replacement hardware.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this are often caused by the length of the ribbon cable connecting to display to the board, or by its vicinity to other wires. Try routing the ribbon cable away from other wires, and use a shorter one if possible.

Comment: Thanks - I'll see what I ca do.  There are two ribbon cables - no problem with them being close to each other, right?